# What is the best practice to populate a StructuredProperty through the ndb.Model constructor?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I looked into the `ndb` GitHub sample code, but I couldn't find any example
which shows on how to create a `ndb` entity with a constructor that contains a `StructuredProperty`.

Here is the GitHub [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/ndb/modeling/structured_property_models.py).

What if I want to initialize a `Contact` entity with a list of phone numbers and this list of phone number is not a list of `PhoneNumber` objects. Instead it is a list of Python dictionaries.

So, given the following `Model` classes:

```
class PhoneNumber(ndb.Model):
    """A model representing a phone number."""
    phone_type = ndb.StringProperty(
        choices=('home', 'work', 'fax', 'mobile', 'other'))
    number = ndb.StringProperty()


class Contact(ndb.Model):
    """A Contact model that uses StructuredProperty for phone numbers."""
    # Basic info.
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    birth_day = ndb.DateProperty()

    # Address info.
    address = ndb.StringProperty()

    phone_numbers = ndb.StructuredProperty(PhoneNumber, repeated=True)
```

I want to create a `Contact` using the following Python dictionaries:

```
phone_number_dicts = [{"phone_type" : "home", number = 122}, {"phone_type" : "work", number = 123}]

contact = Contact(name = "some name", birthday = "some day", phone_numbers = phone_number_dicts)
```

1. Am I required to convert a dict to a `ndb` entity explicitly?
2. Can I override `ndb` constructor which converts a dict to a `ndb` entity and assign?
3. Any other better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
phone_number_dicts = [{"phone_type" : "home", number = 122}, {"phone_type" : "work", number = 123}]
contact = Contact(name = "some name", birthday = "some day", phone_numbers = phone_number_dicts)
```

You would need to have something like this:

```
phone_numbers = [
    PhoneNumber(phone_type="home", number=123),
    PhoneNumber(phone_type="work", number=123)
]
contact = Contact(name="some name", birthday="some day", phone_numbers=phone_numbers)
```

i.e. make a list of `PhoneNumber` entities rather than a list of `dict`s.

You may also pass a dict to an ndb entity in order to populate it with the [`populate` method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/modelclass#instance_methods), i.e. if you already have the line

```
phone_number_dicts = [{"phone_type" : "home", number = 122}, {"phone_type" : "work", number = 123}]
```

that you have no control over, you could then do

```
phone_numbers = [PhoneNumber().populate(**entity) for entity in phone_number_dicts]
```

to create a list of `PhoneNumber`s from an existing list of `dict`s which you then again pass to the `Contact` constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So it means, I have to convert dict to ndb entity before passing to constructor. There is no other way such that ndb  automatically maps dict to ndb properties?

Comment: Pretty much... If you want to store a `dict` or a `list` of `dict`s - look into [`PickleProperty` or `JsonProperty `](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#types).

Answer (score 0):

Simply override the `PhoneNumber` constructor, so that you can pass in a dict as `kwargs` to its constructor via the `Contact` constructor.

```
class PhoneNumber(ndb.Model):
    phone_type = ndb.StringProperty(
        choices=('home', 'work', 'fax', 'mobile', 'other'))
    number = ndb.StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PhoneNumber, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


class Contact(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    birth_day = ndb.DateProperty()
    address = ndb.StringProperty()
    phone_numbers = ndb.StructuredProperty(PhoneNumber, repeated=True)
    company_title = ndb.StringProperty()
    company_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    company_description = ndb.TextProperty()
    company_address = ndb.StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Contact, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs:
            self.phone_numbers = []
            for kwarg in kwargs.pop('phone_numbers'):
                if isinstance(kwarg, PhoneNumber):
                    self.phone_numbers.append(kwarg)
                else:
                    p = PhoneNumber(**kwarg)
                    self.phone_numbers.append(p)
```

In this way you can pass a dictionary representation of your `PhoneNumber` entities to the `Contact` constructor or a dictionary representation of the `PhoneNumber` properties to the `PhoneNumber` constructor.

Here are a few test cases I tried via the **Interactive Console** of the `dev_appserver.py`:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

from models import Contact, PhoneNumber

kwargs = {
    'phone_numbers': [{
        'phone_type': 'home',
        'number': '123',
    }, {
        'phone_type': 'work',
        'number': '456',
    }, {
        'phone_type': 'fax',
        'number': '789',
    }]
}

c = Contact(**kwargs)
print 'Test Case 1:'
print c
print

kwargs = {
    'phone_numbers': [
        PhoneNumber(**{'phone_type': 'home','number': '123'}),
        PhoneNumber(**{'phone_type': 'work','number': '456'}),
        PhoneNumber(**{'phone_type': 'fax', 'number': '789'})
    ]
}

c = Contact(**kwargs)
print 'Test Case 2:'
print c
print

c = Contact(
    phone_numbers=[
        PhoneNumber(phone_type='home', number='123'),
        PhoneNumber(phone_type='work', number='456'),
        PhoneNumber(phone_type='fax', number='789')
    ]
)
print 'Test Case 3:'
print c
print
```

**Output**:

```
Test Case 1:
Contact(phone_numbers=[PhoneNumber(number='123', phone_type='home'), 
PhoneNumber(number='456', phone_type='work'), 
PhoneNumber(number='789', phone_type='fax')])

Test Case 2:
Contact(phone_numbers=[PhoneNumber(number='123', phone_type='home'), 
PhoneNumber(number='456', phone_type='work'), 
PhoneNumber(number='789', phone_type='fax')])

Test Case 3:
Contact(phone_numbers=[PhoneNumber(number='123', phone_type='home'), 
PhoneNumber(number='456', phone_type='work'), 
PhoneNumber(number='789', phone_type='fax')])
```

As expected, each case elicits the same `Contact` objects.